# Pie Chart is not showing correct value due to asynchronous data retrieve in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts, angularjs-directive

When I'm debugging in chrome, I can see that value of `scope.item.sizeUsed` and `scope.item.freeSpace` is loaded but it's not appearing in chart. These two are large value like: 2147483648. Can anyone help me out finding the solution?

HTML:

```
 <div>
      <div class="hc-pie" id="aaa" item="dataVolume"></div>
 </div>
```

Angular JS directive snippet:

```
.directive('hcPie', function () {
    var firstValue = 1;
    return {
      restrict: 'C',
      replace: true,
      template: '<div id="container" style="margin: 0 auto">aa</div>',
      scope: {
            item: '='
          },
      link: function (scope, element, attrs, filter) {
        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
          chart: {
            renderTo: $(element).attr('id')
          },
          title: {
            text: ""
          },
          credits: {
            enabled: false
          },
          series: [{
            type: 'pie',
            data: [
                {
                    name: 'Used Space',
                    y: scope.item.sizeUsed
                },
                {
                    name: 'Free Space',
                    y: scope.item.freeSpace
                }
            ]
          }]
        });
      }
    }
  });
```

Comment: How are the values retrieved? Static in controller, by $http or something else?

Comment: values retrieved in controller via http request. Values are retrieving fine (i can view them in debug mode)

Comment: My guess is that the directive is compiled and rendered before the values are retrieved.

Comment: what will be the solution in that case? @tesseKATT

Comment: Will the data be retrieved only once or will it continue to update?

Comment: data will be retrieved only once

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the chart data is retrieved asynchronously you need to defer the creation of the chart until the data is available.

The simplest way is to use `ng-if` on the element with your directive, for example:

```
<div ng-if="ready" class="hc-pie" id="aaa" item="dataVolume"></div>
```

And set `ready` to `true` when the data is retrieved.

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/2NcubQLEjb2qJfnMJb7C?p=preview

Comment: do i need **chartDirective.js** and **dashboardController.js** in any use?

Comment: No I apologize, I reused an old Plunker and just forgot to remove them. I updated the Plunker.

Answer (score 0):

you should add tooltip and plotOptions in your config.
such as:

```
    tooltip: {
        pointFormat: '{point.name}: <b>{point.y:.1f}</b>'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            allowPointSelect: true,
            cursor: 'pointer',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.y:.1f}',
                style: {
                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
                }
            }
        }
    },
```

Comment: oh, sorry. I misunderstand you question.